# URL in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am persisting the data in a textbox before redirecting the page to another. When the user clicks the back button in the page load function of the page (in javascript) I am getting the data from the textbox like

```
var pageval = $('#grid')
 .load('/Dealer/AllClaims?page=5&__=634673230919806673 #grid', CallBackFunction);
```

I want to send an AJAX call by using the URL from the above data. I.e from `/Dealer/AllClaims?page=5&__=634673230919806673 #grid`. So I replaced the 'pageval' unnecessary data with (.replace()) in javascript. Now I store it as

```
var urlmain = '/Dealer/AllClaims?page=5&__=634673230919806673 #grid';
```

When I send an AJAX call with this 'urlmain' like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: urlmain,

    success: function (data) {
        $("#allclaimsdiv").html(data);
    },
```

it throws error like 'status not found' as the URL is like

**http://localhost:46408/Dealer/%22Dealer/GetDealerClaims?page=3&__=634673387913756213**

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

The above bold data is there in the URL before users click on the back button. I think it is concatenating the data.

But for testing purpose I had given directly the URL as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Dealer/AllClaims?page=5&__=634673230919806673 #grid",

    success: function (data) {
        $("#allclaimsdiv").html(data);
    },
```

Then it works fine.

What is the difference between these two? Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a problem in the called url:

first: there is a /22 which stands for a url-encoded doublequote

second: you have Dealer two times in the url - so you may have to remove /Dealer from your `urlmain`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a quote character getting encoded somewhere along the line? The reason I'm wondering is the URL you've given in bold has "%22" in it:

```
http://localhost:46408/Dealer/%22Dealer/
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for some info on what certain characters get encoded to.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error means a problem has occurred on your web server. Check your server log files or enable error reporting for more info - that might give you some hints or even tell you exactly what's wrong.